# MySQL character_set_server won't take effect

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to have my MySQL server use UTF8 as the default collation and character set. I am able to set everything except for the `character_set_server` which always takes `latin1` as value.

I have put 'character-set-server=utf8' in my my.cnf, but when I run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE character_set_server`, I always get latin1.

If someone could bring me some help it would really be appreciated.

BTW: I'm running MySQL 5.6.19 on MacOS 10.9

Thanks

Comment: I haven't been able to solve this either.
Does anyone know what the issue is about?

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this for change character set of table :

```
mysql> set global character_set_server=utf8;
mysql> set session character_set_server=utf8;
```

And also change table charcter set:

```
mysql> alter table test_latin1 default charset utf8;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can get it to work by running a query to set the character set at the beginning of my script, but I'd really like to do that in my my.cnf file. But I think I will do that for now.